# select count(*) in WHERE Clause needing a comparison operator

Tags: postgresql

Kinda new to SQL so I was reading up on some queries and chanced upon this (https://iggyfernandez.wordpress.com/2011/12/04/day-4-the-twelve-days-of-sql-there-way-you-write-your-query-matters/)

The part that got me curious is the aggregate query in the WHERE Clause. This is probably my misunderstanding but how does the author's code (shown below) run? I presumed that Count(*) - or rather aggregate functions cannot be used in the WHERE clause and you need a HAVING for that ?

```
SELECT per.empid, per.lname
FROM personnel per
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM payroll pay WHERE pay.empid = per.empid AND pay.salary = 199170) > 0;
```

My second question would be why the comparison operator (>0) is needed ? I was playing around and noticed that it would not run in PostgreSQL without the >0; also reformatting it to have a HAVING by Clause massively improves the query execution time

```
SELECT per.empid, per.lname 
FROM personnel per
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT per.empid FROM payroll pay WHERE pay.empid = per.empid AND pay.salary = 199170)
GROUP BY per.empid, per.lname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses in your version, then your query will be a more efficient query that is equivalent to the original.

In the original query, `count(*)` appears in the `SELECT` list of a subquery. You can use a parenthesized subquery almost anywhere in an SQL statement.